# Extract text value from an object to set the text in a listView

Tags: arrays, listview, kotlin

I'm trying set the text in my listView to the string value in my FavJokes class.

```
class FavJokes {
var index: Int? = null
var string: String? = null
}
```

When ever a user favorites a joke, I create a FavObject instance and assign it values for the index(as the Jokes are stored in an array) and the string value of the joke.

```
val newFav = FavJokes()
newFav.index = primaFreeze!!
newFav.string = ("${questionProvider.quesRegistry[primaFreeze!!]}... ${answerProvider.ansRegistry[primaFreeze!!]}")
favorites.add(newFav)
```

When I try to use this array of FavJoke objects as the datasource for my listView what I see is my project id and ".FavJokes@ee8e3e" show up on the listView itself.

I don't think I should populate the listView with just the string value for the joke because for my setOnItemClick{} method, the view I segue to is going to need the index of the joke in order to populate the textView with the correct joke.

I'm new to kotlin/Java started learning it about 3 days ago, but I do have some Swift experience. In Swift I could use an IndexPath object to get/set the values for my tableView. Is there such an object or a method that I can access and set the TextView.text values in Kotlin/Java?

Answer (score 0):

In Android you set an adapter on the list view and then add a setOnItemClickListener, which when called will be provided with the index of the item in the list.

One the simplest adapters is an [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/124438/android-listview-tutorial) from a familiar source.

And here is a quick example from some existing code.

in OnCreateView I get my list view.

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_target_selection, container, false)
        targetList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.names_list) as ListView
        return rootView
    }
```

then in my onResume I receive an array of objects which I then use to create my adapter.

```
    disposables.add(telescopeInterface.namesListStream.subscribe {
        println("here is the names list")
        namesList = it
        namesListAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesList?.names)
        println("setting up list view with the updated list")
        setupListView()
    })
```

then in the setupListView() I assign the adapter to the list view and add a listener.

```
   private fun setupListView() {
        namesListAdapter?.let { targetList.adapter = it }
        targetList.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
            targetSelectionListenter?.targetSelected()
            val entry = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)
            println("item $entry")
            telescopeInterface.sendSelectedTarget(entry as DSOCatalogNameEntry)
        }
    }
```

The full object remains in the list, the adapter is just used to select what is displayed in the list view, then you get the index of the selection, which you then use to extract the full object from your source list.

Comment: Thanks, @nPn it took some doing but I was able to tap into the listView and its datasource. After consulting about a dozen different sources, including the link you sent, I was able to hack together the code to get the job done!